# ap_log_error not logging in my apache module

Tags: c, apache, logging

I have this code in an apache module I'm working on, which is registered using ap_hook_child_init():

```
static class_name *mc;

static void child_init(apr_pool_t *pool, server_rec *s)
{
    ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_INFO, 0, s, "this pointer should be null: %pp", mc);
    mc  = mc_alloc();
    ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_INFO, 0, s, "this pointer should not be null: %pp", mc);
}
```

The problem: I am not seeing these log messages!

I am certain that this function is being called and that the call to `mc_alloc()` is working because when I log from other parts of the modules (like in the request handler), I see the log messages and get a valid result for the pointer. This also tells me that logging is working.

Is it my code that is wrong or my expectations? Can one not issue a log message during an ap_hook_child_init callback? If not, how else might I log that a child was init'ed?

Comment: OK. I made some other tests and I'm certain it's being called. The obvious test, which I did, was to check for NULL in a request handler, then to comment out the call to `mc_alloc()` and try again. The results were different, so now I'm certain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out that this wasn't a code problem, it was a configuration problem.

In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/my_site.conf` I had set `LogLevel Info` in my `<VirtualHost>` section, which apparently does not set it for the whole server.

I discovered this by changing from `APLOG_INFO` to `APLOG_CRIT`. Once I did that the messages appeared in the log. So I knew the *server* was properly logging and my code was working.

This lead me to believe that there were separate possible LogLevel settings and that I had probably been too specific with where mine was. Adding a `LogLevel Info` directive outside the `<VirtualHost>` section apparently was needed to set the whole server to log more messages than the default.